# Excel 2010 using Barcode scanner and Updating row based on scanned input

Tags: triggers, excel-2010, barcode-scanner, worksheet

I have researched on line for sample code that shows two things, 1 how to trigger a macro to run when scanning a barcode and the string ends with an "enter" key, and how to use the scanned data to search for and update a row in a worksheet.

The USB scanner sends data to any application as if it is keyboard input and is terminated with an Enter key.

I want to  scan in a number and then when the enter key is detected have the program "lookup" the number in a master data sheet and insert the current date/time into a cell that is 5 cells to the right of the cell that has the data that was matched.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create form in Excel and set procedure

```
Private Sub UserForm_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
```

When key will be pressed you'll get `KeyCode`. Even on "Enter" key.

So you just accumulate stream from scanner until it'll be Enter (`KeyCode 13` or `10` maybe, you can experiment), and then you work with the stream you got.